# Is it ever explained why people never ask about or fear Grimoire Weiss?

Tags: nier

Throughout the game there are multiple points where it's specifically mentioned that…

> …both Kainé and Emil camp/sleep outside towns (or are even forced to do so),…

…because people don't understand and fear them.

The world we're presented is in general on a rather medieval level regarding technology and knowledge. There are a few machines (either created new, like the waterwheel in Nier's village, or from the "old world", like the robots in the scrap heap), but overall a floating book should feel rather suspicious or scary to your average person. There's a certain level of magic, but it's pretty much always associated with Shades, something people clearly fear.

However, it seems absolutely nobody ever questions, asks about, or simply fears Grimoire Weiss (comparing him to a cookbook at best, so people clearly see him as a book, not just we as observers). Is this ever mentioned or explained?